# What is the order in a priority queue?

Tags: java, priority-queue

I am learning about priority queues in class now doing an assignment in which I am using a Priority queue class that my professor made and creating insert/remove methods for it. The constructor and preset variables look like this:

```
private Item queue[];
private int order;
private int size;

public PriorityQueue(int ord, int s) {
    queue = new Item[s];
    order = ord;
    size = 0;
}
```

I understand that the s input is the capacity of the array of items, and I understand that the order is referring to which Items in the queue have priority, but I am a bit confused on what my input for the order should be, considering an int.

Comment: This is a question for your instructor. There's no objectively correct answer here.

Comment: In this case it seems to mean whether the queue should be ordered lowest-to-highest or highest-to-lowest. It should really be a boolean variable, not an `int`

Comment: That would make sense to me, I'll ask him today. Thanks for the help everyone!